# How to implement lock mechanism in a Firebase node?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, transactions, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use a lock mechanism in a Firebase node. 
I have this structure in my multiplayer game :

```
-lobby{
   - wait room{
      - n9Meavvia9XHBjefBfE9kjtID6x2{
        - challengeId: "waiting"
        - imageURL: "waiting"
        - myURLImage: "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p100x100..."
        - player1: "waiting"
    }
  }
}
```

In my logic, a user that search for a game, should set these parameters (for example `challengeId`), and then the user that is in the wait room, is removed by the wait room, and a match is created. if there aren't users in the wait room, the user who initially search, should be putted in the wait room.

My problem is when more users search at the same time for an user in the wait room, they create two match and it's incorrect. i tried to use Firebase transaction, but I had the same problem. I'm sorry for the incorrect English, but I'm Italian. :)

This is my transaction code :

```
let waitNode = self.thisGameRoot.child("wait room")
    waitNode.runTransactionBlock({(_ currentData: FIRMutableData) -> FIRTransactionResult in

        //self.i += 1
        if currentData.hasChildren() {
            print("HAS CHILDREN!!!!!!, modifico e setto")
            let key = (currentData.children.allObjects[0] as AnyObject).key!!
            //key del primo player in sala d'attesa
            let newData = self.setAdversaryParameters(adversaryKey: key, waitNode: waitNode, data : currentData)
            return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: newData)


        }
        else {
            print("NON ho modificato i dati")
            // torna un value uguale a quello di partenza, non ha cambiato nulla
            return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        }


    }, andCompletionBlock: {(_ error: Error?, _ committed: Bool, _ snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot?) -> Void in
        print("transaction n: " ,self.i)
        if error != nil {
            print("Transaction Error: \(error)")
        }


        if committed {
            print("dati impegnati,in lavorazione(LOCK)")

        }

        print("Final Value: \(snapshot!.value))")
        if self.modified && snapshot!.exists(){
            _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.segue), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

        }
        else{
            self.putInWaitRoom(waitNode: waitNode)
        }
    })
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks!